# Wifi broken on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking

I have a HP Pavilion laptop that shipped with Windows 8, that I upgraded to Windows 10 last spring. It's been working fairly well so far. Until recently.

Last week, my computer stopped finding Wifi networks completely. I figured this was a hardware issue, because my computer has been having problems with the audio jack as well. But it shouldn't be...because when I live-boot Ubuntu from a USB, my computer will gladly connect to Wifi. I tried turning airplane mode on and off, and restarted the computer several times, but was not able to make Wifi work in Windows. As far as I can tell, Windows is up to date (at least, to the last time it was connected to the Internet).

What troubleshooting steps am I missing? Why might Windows not want to connect?

Comment: Possibly https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-networking/problems-connecting-to-the-internet/f121306e-fab5-411d-833f-e4490ecb8b5c?tm=1481238027434

Comment: @DavidMarshall Thank you. The first page suggests restart, but links to another page (https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/10741/windows-10-fix-network-connection-issues) that might have what I'm looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have an Asus on Windows 10 Home. a little while ago before this writing, Windows forced the update. My Wifi immediately went offline so I went ahead and clicked to "Update and Restart" Once restarted, the PC still wouldn't detect any wifi. Windows Troubleshooting tool useless.

Very next thing I did...
Plugged in an ethernet cable.
Opened Device Manager
Right-clicked on the entry for the Wifi-adapter/driver
Selected Uninstall
    MOST IMPORTANT: During the uninstall it will ask if I wanted to completely delete the device driver from the PC. Select Yes or click the checkbox for yes. (can't remember which it was)
Once the driver was completely uninstalled and deleted, I had Device Manager run a "Scan for Hardware Changes."
That scan triggered Windows to find and install the driver. 
Afterwards Wifi was back up and running no problem.
I have worked for several hours now straight with the occasional shutdown/restart to make sure the issue was resolved and it appears to be. So far so good, fingers crossed it stays that way.

Very next chance I get, I'm going to purchase a full version copy of Pro or Enterprise either through my work or the nearest Microsoft store. I'm not playing this stupid game with them and these forced updates anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so the issue took care of itself. I have no idea what the problem was, or what made it go away, but after another reboot my computer is able to connect to Wifi networks when using Windows so problem solved!

Comment: If a reboot fixed it then it could well be the latest Windows Update round that has brought down a lot of network adaptors, especially if you could *see* but not *connect* to them: http://www.theregister.co.uk/2016/12/14/microsoft_windows_10_dhcp/

Comment: @Mokubai I dunno. I honestly have no clue what fixed it, because it took several reboots before the problem went away. Also, the problem included not being able to _see_ networks at all, so... ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Well, I do believe there was a windows update in the last week. And its a much more plausible answer than "it just did the damnest thing". Granted I've had that happen once or twice ><

Comment: @JourneymanGeek Fair. However, I'm pretty sure that my machine "just did the damnest thing," because I installed the update with the number that was supposed to fix this (at least, according to Mokubai's link) only _after_ the problem went away.